# Get specific value from Firebase JSON tree based on value

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I am writing a Javascript web app using Firebase. If I have data like this in my JSON tree:

```
users
     session1
          screenname:Bill
     session2
          screenname:Steve
```

...and I know the session number, how can I grab the "name" of the user? I have tried this:

```
valUsers.child('session1').child('screenname').once('value', function(data){
     console.log(data);
});
```

But that does not seem to work. I'm guessing I have a syntax issue?

Comment: Is valUsers a reference to your Firebase object? Also have you looked at .val()? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/val.html

Comment: Yes, that was it. I needed data.val() instead of just data. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close, but needed to use [DataSnapshot.val()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/val.html) as shown below to access the point you want.

```
var ref = new Firebase('yourfirebaselocation/users');
var sessionNum = 'session1';
ref.child(sessionNum + '/screenname').once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  var specificScreenname = specificPoint.val();
}
```

When working with Firebase, you may want to also explore working with [Promise objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility). This would allow you to create some repeatable functions that can reuse your reference on multiple locations and also give Firebase time to respond to your query.

```
var ref = new Firebase('yourfirebaselocation/users');

function getUser(theRef, location) {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      theRef.child(location).once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
        resolve(dataSnapshot);
      });
    });
}

getUser(ref, specificlocationvariable).then( function(val) {
  specificScreenname = val.val();
});
```

You don't specify other than 'JavaScript' so do keep in mind that Promises are an ECMAScript 6 proposal with some compatibility issues, but a lot of the JS frameworks have an implementation for it that smooth that issue (Angular, Ember, etc).